# Trailhead Error: Protect Your Data in Salesforce -> Restrict Login Hours and IP Ranges

Tags: trailhead, ip

I have started this challenge in 2 separate orgs - this last one is brand new.  I have 2 issues that I'm getting error messages on:

1: The IP Address instructions cannot be followed:
Enter these values:
Start IP Address: 0.0.0.0
End IP Address: 255.255.255.255
Description: San Diego
Because you get this error "Error: The range specified is too large"
[image: Error message]

2: When I try and get a verification (I saved the IP address with what I could), I get this error message:
Step not yet complete in My Trailhead Playground 19
There was an unexpected error while verifying this challenge. Usually this is due to some pre-existing configuration or code in the challenge Org. We recommend using a new Developer Edition (DE) to check this challenge. If you're using a new DE and seeing this error, please post to the developer forums and reference error id: KJOGRDHB
[image: Trailhead error]

This is a new DEV Org created for this challenge.  And after I posted on the [SF DEV Community](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000IDeNQAW), I also tried again by creating ANOTHER Playground and starting from scratch and got the same error...twice!  So, I've tried in 3 separate playgrounds :(

Any ideas on how to overcome?

Cheers, Nat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to salesforce help docs, it says The start and ends IP addresses must be in an IPv4 range and include no more than 33,554,432 addresses (225, a /7 CIDR block) for Organization.

you can set login IP range from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 for profile but not for Organization level.

Read more here:- [Set Trusted IP Ranges for Your Organization](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=security_networkaccess.htm&type=5)

As per trailhead, it is asking to Restrict the Login IP Range on the Custom: Support Profile.  Go to setup, search for profile and select it. click on the profile name called custom: Support profile. Under Login IP Ranges, click New and enter the details.